# Telegram Usage for Registration site

Tags: updates, telegram, messaging

I have a registration site that accepts registrations for an event. 
This is based on woocommerce Word Press theme.

For every successful registration, woocommerce is sending a) Registration receipt b) Registration processed c) If registration went on hold 4) Customer Note 5) Ticket for the event (after completion) process

All these 5-6 customer touch point mail contents - I'm catching into files.

My objective is to send these files as well as some additional messages to Registrants through Telegram.

I'm able to do this using Telethon library and a Python script.

However I'm not sure if this is in any way disallowed since it involves many registrants (probably 5000+)

Would Telegram consider this as acceptable usage ?

Has anyone come across similar usage / situation. Please guide me. I do not want to realize that I did something wrong at a later time.

Thank you for your help.

The intended design and messaging Python script / Telethon all are working well.

N/A

Is this acceptable usage ?

Comment: You question is not about the programming but about a service and its ToS. Ask Telegram, not us.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this